# cant send .mp3 files in python telegram bot

Tags: python, bots, telegram

```py
import logging
from telegram import Update, ForceReply
from telegram.ext import Updater, CommandHandler, MessageHandler, Filters, CallbackContext
from telegram.files.audio import Audio


logging.basicConfig(
    format='%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s', level=logging.INFO
)

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)


def start(update: Update, _: CallbackContext) -> None:
    """Send a message when the command /start is issued."""
    user = update.effective_user
    update.message.reply_markdown_v2(
        fr'Hi {user.mention_markdown_v2()}\!',
        reply_markup=ForceReply(selective=True),
    )


def help_command(update: Update, _: CallbackContext) -> None:
    """Send a message when the command /help is issued."""
    update.message.reply_text('Help!')

def sendAudio(update: Update, context: CallbackContext):
    context.bot.sendAudio(chat_id=update.message.chat_id, Audio=open("hxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.mp3", "rb"), timeout=360)


def main() -> None:

    updater = Updater("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx")


    dispatcher = updater.dispatcher

    dispatcher.add_handler(CommandHandler("start", start))
    dispatcher.add_handler(CommandHandler("help", help_command))
    dispatcher.add_handler(CommandHandler("send", sendAudio))

    updater.start_polling()

    updater.idle()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

this is my code when i send /send it showing this error

```
2021-05-28 16:16:18,309 - telegram.ext.dispatcher - ERROR - No error handlers are registered, logging exception.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Acer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\telegram\ext\dispatcher.py", line 447, in process_update
    handler.handle_update(update, self, check, context)
  File "C:\Users\Acer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\telegram\ext\handler.py", line 160, in handle_update
    return self.callback(update, context)
  File "e:\Projects\Python\Telegram bot\echo.py", line 28, in sendAudio
    context.bot.sendAudio(chat_id=update.message.chat_id, Audio=open("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.mp3", "rb"), timeout=360)
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.mp3'
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? ['invalid argument' error and python not reading file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26662247/invalid-argument-error-and-python-not-reading-file)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bot method [`send_audio`](https://python-telegram-bot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/telegram.bot.html#telegram.Bot.send_audio) has an argument `audio` with a lower case `a` - you wrote `Audio` with a captial `A` instead.
Note that you can simplify your code with the [`reply_audio`](https://python-telegram-bot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/telegram.message.html#telegram.Message.reply_audio) shortcut.

---

Disclaimer: I'm currently the maintainer of `python-telegram-bot`

Comment: `def help_command(update: Update, _: CallbackContext) -> None:
    update.message.reply_audio("https://xxxxxxxxxxxx/xxx.mp3")`                                                                                                        like this ?

Comment: this link is working `http://www.mlk4.info/audio/71000/Snehaya-K-A-Suneka-Charuni-musiclk=audio.mp3` but this link not wokring `https://www.fmderana.lk/helpers/download.php?id=5855&file=Himasha_Manuppriya_Dewiyane.mp3` it saying File `"C:\Users\Acer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\telegram\utils\request.py", line 273, in _request_wrapper
    raise BadRequest(message)
telegram.error.BadRequest: Wrong file identifier/http url specified` how to fix that